# Use gdal_calc to convert Z values to negatives

Tags: gdal

I've been using the `Raster Calculator` in QGIS to convert a GeoTIFF's Z values to negative by using `-abs(layername)`

I now want to do this in GDAL so I tried the following

```
gdal_calc -a c:/users/public/input.tif --outfile c:/users/public/output.tif --calc "-abs(-a)"
```

but I get the error

> No calculation provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that the gdal_calc command requires `--calc="expression"`

I had missed out the equals, preventing it from working